# Is there a way to do a "neutral" class in a multi-classification problem?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, loss-function, multiclass-classification

If i am doing a multi-classification problem, is there a way to essentially make a class an "unsure" class? For example if my model doesn't have a very strong prediction, it should default to this class. Like when you take a test, some tests penalize you for wrong answers, some don't. I want to do a custom loss function that doesn't penalize my model for guessing the neutral class, but does penalize if the model makes a prediction that is wrong. Is there a way to do what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

For classifiers using a one-hot encoded softmax output layer, the outputs can be interpreted as a probability that the input falls into each of the categories. e.g. if your model has outputs (cat, dog, frog), then an output of (0.6, 0.2, 0.2) means the input has (according to the classifier) a 60% chance of being a cat and a 20% chance for each of being a dog or frog.

In this case, when the model is uncertain it can (and will) have an output where no one class is particularly likely, e.g. (0.33, 0.33, 0.33). There's no need to add a separate 'Other' category.

---

Separate to this, it might be difficult to train an "unsure" category, unless you have specific input examples that you want to train the model to classify as "unsure".

Comment: I do understand that but i wanted a discrete way to determine if a prediction was not strong enough. I would rather not have to arbitrarily decide the cutoff for when a prediction is strong enough and just let my model only make a prediction when it has some sort of edge.

Comment: At the end of the day, whether or not a prediction is "strong enough" is arbitrary, at least as far as I know of

Comment: I've added to my answer a bit more about what you'd need to easily create an "unsure" category

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of creating a custom loss function, and when my model guesses the unsure category it would add half the average loss. My thinking is that a correct guess would still be better than guessing unsure, but guessing unsure wouldn't be as negative as guessing incorrectly.

Comment: That could work. Let us know by posting an answer if you find it works well

Comment: Will do. My only concern it that i'm not that good at working in Tensorflow and i fear my solutions will be a lot more expensive computationally than the default keras crossentropy functions. But we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the very same problem.
I tried using a neutral class, but the neural net will either put nothing in it, or everything in it depending on the reduced loss.
After some searching, it looks like we are trying to achieve "neural network uncertainty estimation". One of the ways to achieve that is to run your image 100 times in your neural net with random dropouts and see how many times it hits the same class.

This blog post explains it well : https://www.inovex.de/blog/uncertainty-quantification-deep-learning/

This video also : https://medium.com/deeplearningmadeeasy/how-to-add-uncertainty-to-your-neural-network-afb5f855e66a

I will let you know and publish here if I have some results with that.